# Can MongoDB instances in Google App Engine flexible be stateful?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, google-app-engine, docker

Now that I have managed to deploy one of my services (an API written in PHP) to GAE flexible using a custom Dockerfile,
I would like to deploy another service that would be a Mongodb database, so that my PHP API can store data in Mongodb.

Because I would like to build all of my microservices within GAE flexible, I was thinking of using the same process, which is deploying another custom Dockerfile for building my Mongodb instances.

Now I was wondering if that is the correct approach? I am concerned about the statefullness of my Mongodb instances in that case. Will the data be lost when the instances are restarted or when I deploy another version, is there another more recommended approach for what I am trying to do?

PS: I would like not to have to use Google Datastore, mainly since I'm using the Symfony PHP framework with a lot of useful bundles to interact with Mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend deploying MongoDB on GAE, you could easily loose your data, and I don't think GAE features were made for hosting databases. I think it'd give more headaches than solutions.

If you want to use docker images, I'd suggest using [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/). You just need to remember that you must use a persistent disk in order to not loose data. For development and even small production apps it should fulfill all your needs.

But from my experience, it's much better and efficient to deploy your MongoDB server on Google Compute Engine instances. You can use [Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/docs/) to deploy (cloud launcher will launch your MongoDB almost ready to use, you'd just need to add the users/authentication)

Comment: I think that deploying Mongo on GCE is indeed what I am going to do. Thank you.